# What is a solution to test if a string contains a specific sub string in SAS?

Tags: sas

I am trying to figure out how to test in a SAS DATA step if a variable value is contained in a string.
Let say I have the following:

```
Variable='some string'

String='ABC;EFG;IJKL;MNOPQ'.
```

I want to build a test returning 'OK' if:

- Variable='ABC'
- Variable='EFG'
- Variable='IJKL'
- Variable='MNOPQ'

Returning 'NOT OK' otherwise;

I have the following code:

```
FIND(String,TRIM(Variable)) GE 1 THEN PUT 'OK';
```

The previous line would make the test return OK if

```
Variable = 'AB' ;

Variable = 'G;IJKL;M' ;

Variable = ';' ;
```

...

Which is not what I want.

Do you have any idea ?
Thank You

Answer (score 1):

The following code makes use of `indexw()`, using '`;`' as a word delimiter:

```
data have;
   string   = 'ABC;EFG;IJKL;MNOPQ';
   input variable $;
   datalines4;
ABC
EFG
IJKL
MNOPQ
AB
G;IJKL;M
;
;;;;

data want;
   set have;

   length result $ 8;
   result = ifc(indexw(string,strip(variable),';'),'OK','NOT OK');
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the FINDW() function.  You can tell it what characters are used to mark the end of words. You can also use the modifier options to tell it to automatically trim the trailing blanks and/or ignore case.  It will return the location in the string where the variable value was found.

```
location=findw("ABC;EFG;IJKL;MNOPQ",var,';','t');
```

with 0 meaning it was not found.  Since SAS will treat any non-zero value as true you can just use the result in your IF statement.

```
if findw("ABC;EFG;IJKL;MNOPQ",var,';','t') then put var 'FOUND';
else put var 'NOT FOUND';
```